# PHP How to remove white spaces, obfuscating the output HTML CODE on the fly at the Server

Tags: php, html, encryption, obfuscation

I have a simple website in PHP.

My website does not use any Data Source, just some simple PHP scripts to allow some basic functionality.

As for my understanding when a User request my website the PHP code generates the HTML code that will be read by their browser.

I need to make difficult (in some how obfuscate) the HTML generated, so if the user would save a HTML page the code would be difficult to modify and uneasy to interpreter.

My basic need are basically COMPRESSING the HTML:

- Eliminate white space. So all code would be packed in few line. Making it in some how human unreadable
- Encode the HTML (optional)

Because I have many pages in my website. I'm looking for an automatic solution so I can add some code in one place and have for the next moment all pages output as described above.

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that since white space is significant in HTML, although multiple spaces are compressed down to one), removing them all may cause your pages to render differently.

Comment: Even if you obfuscate the HTML, it is pretty easy to extract the (formatted) HTML contents from a page using the various web developer tools like firebug or chrome's dom tool.

Comment: Ok I understand your points. So how can I protect my website from be fully downloaded maybe modified an be used on another domain or server? What are the protection? Thanks

Comment: I am sure there are tons of similar questions already but I see no reason why it's me should be searching for them, not the OP. So, just "not a real question".

Comment: If you want your site to be display somewhere, it must be downloaded, so no.

Comment: What is so special, or private, in your output HTML, that you feel the need to obfuscate it?

Comment: Please guys, add a comment when down-voting so I can improve my questioning. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use eval function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php or output buffering: http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php and than modify the result. But obfuscating HTML itself is pointless. There are many tools for code formating capable of reverting the code to human-friendly form.

If you want the result to by hard to change, why don't you output a PDF file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use output buffering and "obfuscate" your output in a global callback function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compress the generated HTML pages on the way to the user, enable compression by i.e. using [mod_gzip](http://schroepl.net/projekte/mod_gzip/) or [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html) in apache.

If, on the other hand, you want "protection" - this is not possible. The music and film industry have been trying that for decades. You could of course generate a big fat image (jpeg) from your page and serve that as an image map :)